# Laravel 5 Api & Website Architecture

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I have a large Laravel 5 app I'm having trouble structuring in a manageable way. I've looked at several different examples, but am hoping for someone who's had experience with this type of setup to throw their two cents in.

The project consists of:

1. A promotional website and blog
2. A restful API for a mobile app (built with AngularJS)
3. A CMS for managing the blog and several entities used by the app

At some point down the road, the promotional site may use data from the app.

Things seem to get pretty tough to sort through with the API, blog and CMS all residing in the same Laravel project. While I love the idea of using Lumen for the API and separating the various services into their own projects, the projects aught to deploy synchronously since they'd be using the same database.

Should I split these into separate code repositories, or is their a good way to organize these within a single Laravel project?

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: When i create a laravel project i seperate my controllers and views in /front /back /api folders. works fine for me even on big projects. I have 3 controllers called ExampleController than though,

Answer (score 1):

Separate packages in terms of deployment, business and workforces always make sense. When designing in a unique architecture, this layers can rest side-by-side with no problem (in php, think namespaces).

I also recommend to take in consideration scale factors while designing the architecture, if applicable.

So just be creative (and thoughtful) while projecting your `PSR-4 autoload classmaps`. If not yet, you [might need](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) this.

Additionally, make sure to cross-polinate your research with http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/packages